# Ruby on Rails find - finds the wrong object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, find

i am new to Ruby on Rails.
I am trying to make a one to many association. I have a "Project" and the Project should have many "Taskbundle".
That is looking fine.

Now i want to show on the page only the taskbundles filtered for that selected project.

I made this in the ProjectController class:

```
def select
    puts "==Projects=="
    puts params[:id]

    @project = Project.find{params[:id]}
    puts @project.id
    session[:project_id] = @project.id

    puts session[:project_id]

    redirect_to taskbundles_path
end
```

I am getting there without problem, but the find method finds the project with the id 3 and not the project with the id 4 ? I checked, the project with id 4 exists.

Output

```
==Projects==
4
3
3


Started GET "/projects/select/4" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-01-05 20:19:03 +0100
Processing by ProjectsController#select as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"4"}
  ?[1m?[35mProject Load (0.0ms)?[0m  SELECT "projects".* FROM "projects"
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/taskbundles
Completed 302 Found in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

I have no idea where i did a mistake?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you got a syntactic problem: `@project = Project.find{params[:id]}` should be `@project = Project.find(params[:id])`. The ID needs to be passed as an argument. Your code creates a ruby block.

Comment: Thank you! I was searching about 2 hours for this "problem" :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use
@project = Project.find_by{params[:id]} instead of Project.find{params[:id]}

if the id doesn't exist find method will give you exception and stop the execution of remaining code where as if you use find_by method it will return nil if the id doesn't exist in the database.